# What caching model does TensorFlow use?

Tags: tensorflow

I read the question here
[TensorFlow - get current value of a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679382/tensorflow-get-current-value-of-a-variable)
and the answer has left me confused.

On one hand, dga says "And to be very clear: Running the variable will
produce only the current value of the variable; it will not run any
assign operations associated with it. It's cheap."

On the other hand, Salvador Dali says "@dga yes, if the variable depends
on n other variables, they also need to be evaluated."

So, which is it? Does evaluating the variable only return its current
value, or does it recompute its value from scratch from the variables it
depends on?

What happens if I evaluate the same variable twice in a row? Does
Tensorflow have any notion of "stale" variables, i.e. variables that
need to be recomputed because their dependencies actually changed (i.e. like in
build system)?

I ask because I work with multiple nets where the partial output of one
net becomes the partial input of another net. I want to fetch the
gradients computed at the input layer of one net and merge+apply them to
the output layer of another net. I was hoping to do this by manually
retrieving/storing gradients in the variables of a graph, and then
running graph operations to backpropagate the gradients. Thus I need to
understand how it all works under the hood.

What I do is similar to this
[How to use Tensorflow Optimizer without recomputing activations in reinforcement learning program that returns control after each iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536340/how-to-use-tensorflow-optimizer-without-recomputing-activations-in-reinforcement), but I can't conclude whether it's possible based on the last answer (experimental support now in?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dga is correct. If you pass a `tf.Variable` object to `tf.Session.run()` TensorFlow will return the current value of the variable, and it will not perform any computation. It is cheap (the cost of a memory copy, or possibly a network transfer in the case of a distributed TensorFlow setup). TensorFlow does not retain any history* about how the value of a `tf.Variable` was updated, so it cannot in general recompute its value from scratch.

---

(* Technically TensorFlow remembers the `tf.Tensor` that was used to *initialize* each variable, so it is possible to recompute the inital value of the variable.)

Comment: OK, everything is cached. Thank you.